# Variavel php em meta tag

Tags: php, javascript, html5

É o seguinte, tenho um player de áudio em html5 e javascript, quando tento compartilhar uma música no face por exemplo, a postagem não vai com o título do áudio, mas apenas com o título da página, minha dúvida é como posso fazer para que ao compartilhar seja mostrado também o nome do áudio que está sendo compartilhado.

Tentei usar uma variável que pega o nome da música em execução, mas a tag "og" não reconhece html:

```
<?php $description = '<span class="center" id="npTitle"></span>';?>
```

tentei chamá-la assim:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description;?>" />
```

Mas não funciona, alguma sugestão, é possível resolver sem ter que reformular todo o player?
Obrigado!

Meu player:
http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.php?ip=hinosSalmosCanticos#0

Comment: A questão é: por quê está tentando colocar um código HTML dentro da tag? Ela não deveria receber apenas o texto referente a variável `$description`?

Comment: Olá @AndersonCarlosWoss, obrigado por perguntar, é porque este texto referente a descrição é dinâmico e muda de acordo com a url, é um player de audio em html5, então quando vc clica em compartilhar ele deve pegar o o valor da tag description, que muda de acordo com o audio que está tocando. caso queiro queira dar uma olhada, de qualquer forma muito obrigado

http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=hinosSalmosCanticos#0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olha, pelo que vi você quer compartilhar as músicas pelos próprios botões do site, aparentemente isso vai ser um app pra Android feito em HTML5, não é necessário seguir o `Title` ou `Description`, pode fazer por variaveis de Javascript que definam uma variavel na URL e que o PHP inicie pela música apontada por este.

Não analisei o seu código HTML pra ver como realmente é feito, mas vou fazer um exemplo simples de como eu faria.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.playlist{
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: blue;
}
audio{
    display:block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-color: grey;
}
</style>
<script>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['ip']) && !empty($_GET['ip'])){
    echo "var ip = '".$_GET['ip']."';\n"; //Pegar nome da playlist
    if(isset($_GET['tck']) && !empty($_GET['tck'])){
        echo "var tck = ".$_GET['tck'].";\n";
    }else{
        echo "var tck = 1;\n";
    }
?>
function playAudio(tgt){
    tck = tgt; //Alterar variavel Global para compartilhamento
    var tracks = document.getElementsByTagName('audio');
    for(t=0;t<tracks.length;t++){
        tracks[t].pause();
        tracks[t].currentTime = 0;
        tracks[t].style.backgroundColor = "grey";
    }
    tracks[tgt-1].play();
    tracks[tgt-1].style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
}

function shareTrack(s){
    var url = "http://www.meusite.com/player/?ip="+ip+"&tck="+tck;
    alert("\nCompartilhando no "+s+" o link\n\n"+url);
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="playAudio(tck)">
<a class="playlist" href="#" id="1" onclick="playAudio(this.id)"><audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"></audio>Audio 1</a>
<br />
<a class="playlist" href="#" id="2" onclick="playAudio(this.id)"><audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"></audio>Audio 2</a>
<br />
<a class="playlist" href="#" id="3" onclick="playAudio(this.id)"><audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"></audio>Audio 3</a>
<br />
<a class="playlist" href="#" id="4" onclick="playAudio(this.id)"><audio src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg"></audio>Audio 4</a>
[<a onclick="shareTrack(this.innerHTML)">Facebook</a>][<a onclick="shareTrack(this.innerHTML)">Whatsapp</a>]
<?php
}else{
?>
</script>
</heead>
<body>
<a href="?ip=playlist1">Playlist1</a><br />
<a href="?ip=playlist2">Playlist2</a><br />
<a href="?ip=playlist3">Playlist3</a><br />
<?php }?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: vou testar aqui, obrigado!

Comment: Desculpa, escrevi errado uma das variáveis. Corrigi, verifica por favor.

Comment: Neste formato funciona, mas quando uso assim:
`<span class="center" id="npTitle"></span>` não funciona, mas de qualquer forma obrigado.

Comment: Poderia explicar claramente o uso de uma TAG html dentro do atributo de outra?

Comment: O uso é para compartilhamento via facebook e whatsapp
Tenho um player de audio e um botão do face para compartilhamento, parece que o face não permite uso de tag dinamico.
segue o link para o audio player em javascript e html5
Ao clicar no botão compartilhar  a tag descrição deveria conter o nome do audio que está sendo compartilhado, mas não está funcionando
http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=3minMateus#0

Comment: Mas essas redes sociais não interpretam essas TAGs mesmo que você codificasse elas com `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Nesse caso já não sei o que fazer, Obrigado RpgBoss

Comment: @MiguelSilva não tem sentido adicionar HTML em tags OpenGraph (`og`), ferramentas como facebook e whatsapp (que usam opengraph) não vão reconhecer o HTML.

Comment: @Guilherme Nascimento que iria exportar o estilo da página paras redes sociais. Mas no Whatsapp a única maneira seria usando a formatação padrão deles. Vou por na resposta pra ele ver.

Comment: @RpgBoss isso creio ser para mensagens de texto, OpenGraph não é texto e nem mensagem, OpenGraph é usado para alimentar "BOTs" e afins, o proprio Whatsapp e Facebook (por compartilhar) irão gerar o box, mas não irão formatar nem com HTML e nem markdown (_text_, ~text~, etc). Detalhes sobre o que é OpenGraph em: http://ogp.me e https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento acho que não consegui ser claro no que pretendo fazer, me desculpe.
É o seguinte, tenho um player de audio em html5 e javascript, quando tento compartilhar uma música no face por exemplo, a postagem não vai com o título do audio, mas apenas com o título da página, minha dúvida é como posso fazer para que ao compartilhar seja mostrado também o nome do audio que está sendo compartilhado. De qualquer modo muito obrigado por seu comentário.
Segue minha página do player:
http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/player.html?ip=hinosSalmosCanticos#0

Comment: @MiguelSilva edita a pergunta por favor, pois a parte do HTML span ali não tem relação com a duvida atual.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editado, poderia verificar se está claro?

Comment: Olha, eu realmente estou custando à entender o que ele quer, mesmo deppois de editada. Eu vou editar a resposta mais uma vez mostrando como colocar o nome da música no título dinamicamente com PHP através de `#` ou `?`.

Comment: @RpgBoss é isso mesmo, sua resposta está no caminho certo, só não consegui fazer funcionar seu código: aqui está ele online:
http://leituracrista.com/audioplayer/teste/

Comment: Você lembrou de colocar na URL o `?` e as variaveis? Editei o código pra ter mais clareza.

Comment: Não precisa usar isset junto com empty, o empty é construtor de linguagem, assim como o isset, dá pra enxugar um pouco o código.

Comment: @RpgBoss agora foi, faltavam as variáveis, agora vou tentar adaptar para meu player, quebrar um pouco a cabeça, se eu conseguir posto aqui os resultados.
Muito Obrigado.